# GridView ButtonField postback not working in IE7?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008, gridview, internet-explorer-7, buttonfield

I have an ASP.Net Web Site with GridView control that in turn contains a ButtonField column. It's supposed to do a postback when this ButtonField is clicked, but that doesn't happen if I click on the button from within the Internet Explorer window that Visual Studio opens while debugging. I can get it to successfully postback when I bring up and click on the ButtonField from an externally-invoked Internet Explorer window or a Firefox window, but never from the window Visual Studio produces.

I'm using:

- Windows Vista Home Premium
- Visual Studio 2008, running as Administrator
- Internet Explorer 7.0.6000.16809
- Firefox 3.0.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've determined the problem is due to running Visual Studio 2008 as Administrator under Windows Vista. Doing so causes some kind of issue with Javascript that prevents GridView ButtonFields from issuing postbacks. Contrary to Microsoft's advice for the previous version of Visual Studio (2005), debugging with Visual Studio 2008 running under Windows Vista requires that the IDE **not** be run using "*Run as Administrator*".

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any javascript added to that button?  If javascript fails onclick it could bring up the debugger when running via VS but any other browser might just be eating the error.

Comment: No javascript has been added to the button, and the issue occurs whether IE debugging is turned on or off.

I have figured out the cause of the problem. I'll insert it as an answer to my own post.